# Why does my method only run once even though i called it 5 times?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Hi I'm a beginner at java and I'm trying to program this Who wants to be a millionaire game. I have set up a method and arrays so the program should repeat with a different question and different answers each time. However, the `questions` method only runs once even though I called it a few times in the main method. Thanks.

```
   //WWTBAM  Adam Lam
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
class WWTBAMGOOD {
  static Random random = new Random(); 
  static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  static int randomnum;
  static int rand=100;
  static int sum = 0;
  static String lifeline1= "1";
  static String lifeline2="2";
  static String lifeline3="3";
  static String a = "a";
  static String b = "b";
  static String c = "c";
  static String d = "d";
  static String guess = "0";
  static String name;
  static String finalanswer = "0";
  static String x = "yes";
  static String y = "no";
  static int num1 = -1;
  static int num2 = -1;
  static int num3=-1;
  static int num4=-1;
  static String[] answerkey = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d",  }; 
  static String[] allquestions1 = { "What does NBA most commonly stand for? \n A. National Basketball Association \n B. New Brunswick Accounting  \n C. Nevada Bowling Association \n D. Nile Boating Associates", "Which country invented hockey? \n A. Iceland \n B. Canada \n C. Australia \n D. China",  "What is the point of soccer? \n A. To find a sock \n B. To get to the other side \n C. To score a ball into the opposing team's net \n D. To see who's the fastest runnner" , "In parts of Europe, North American's soccer is more commonnly called what? \n A. Kicker \n B. European Ball \n C. Tennis Golf \n D. Football" ,  "Which of these is a hockey player? \n A. Wayne Gretzky \n B. Babe Ruth \n C. Steph Curry \n D. Michael Jordan" }; 


  static void questions(){
    do{
    int randomnum = random.nextInt(4);
    } while(rand==randomnum);
    rand = randomnum;
    System.out.println("Remember, you can always use your lifelines. Press 1 for 50/50, 2 for Poll the audience, and 3 for call a friend");
    do{
      do{
        System.out.println (allquestions1[randomnum]);
        guess=scanner.nextLine();
        if ((!guess.equalsIgnoreCase(a) && !guess.equalsIgnoreCase(b) && !guess.equalsIgnoreCase(c) && !guess.equalsIgnoreCase(d)&&!guess.equalsIgnoreCase(lifeline1)&&!guess.equalsIgnoreCase(lifeline2)&&!guess.equalsIgnoreCase(lifeline3))) {
          System.out.println("Invalid Input. Please Try Again. \n\n");
        }
      } while(!guess.equalsIgnoreCase(a) && !guess.equalsIgnoreCase(b) && !guess.equalsIgnoreCase(c) && !guess.equalsIgnoreCase(d)&&!guess.equalsIgnoreCase(lifeline1)&&!guess.equalsIgnoreCase(lifeline2)&&!guess.equalsIgnoreCase(lifeline3));
      System.out.println("Is this your final answer? (yes or no)");
      finalanswer=scanner.nextLine();
    } while (!finalanswer.equalsIgnoreCase(x));

    if (guess.equalsIgnoreCase(answerkey[randomnum])) {
      System.out.println("You got it right! Congrats!");
    }
    else if ((guess.equalsIgnoreCase(a) || (guess.equalsIgnoreCase(b)) || (guess.equalsIgnoreCase(c)) || (guess.equalsIgnoreCase(d)))) {
      System.out.println("Sorry you got it wrong :( \n Better luck next time");

    }

    while(sum<=1){
      if (guess.equals(lifeline1)){
        System.out.println("You chose the 50/50 lifeline!");
        do{
          do{
            System.out.println("Your choices are now between option " + (answerkey[randomnum]) + " and " + ((answerkey [randomnum+1])));
            guess = scanner.nextLine();
            if ((!guess.equalsIgnoreCase(a) && !guess.equalsIgnoreCase(b) && !guess.equalsIgnoreCase(c) && !guess.equalsIgnoreCase(d)&&!guess.equalsIgnoreCase(lifeline1)&&!guess.equalsIgnoreCase(lifeline2)&&!guess.equalsIgnoreCase(lifeline3))) {
              System.out.println("Invalid Input. Please Try Again. \n\n");
            }
          } while(!guess.equalsIgnoreCase(a) && !guess.equalsIgnoreCase(b) && !guess.equalsIgnoreCase(c) && !guess.equalsIgnoreCase(d)&&!guess.equalsIgnoreCase(lifeline1)&&!guess.equalsIgnoreCase(lifeline2)&&!guess.equalsIgnoreCase(lifeline3));

          System.out.println("Is this your final answer? (yes or no)");
          finalanswer=scanner.nextLine();

        } while(!finalanswer.equals(x));
        sum++; 
        if (guess.equals(answerkey[randomnum])) {
          System.out.println("You got it right!!! Congrats " + name+ " !!  You won 100 Dollars!!! \n\n");
        }
        else {
          System.out.println("Sorry you got it wrong :(");

        }
      }
    }
    while (sum<=1) {
      if (guess.equalsIgnoreCase(lifeline2)) {
        System.out.println("You chose the poll the audience lifeline!");

        num1 = random.nextInt(10)+80;
        num2 = random.nextInt(6)+1;
        num3 = random.nextInt(5)+1;
        num4 = 100 - (num1+num2+num3);
        do{
          do{
            System.out.println("The audience, out of 100 people said: \n A. National Basketball Association: "+ (num1)+ " \n B. New Brunswick Accounting: "+num2+ "\n C. Nevada Bowling Association: "+num3+" \n D. Nile River Boating: "+num4 + "\n\n Enter your new guess:");
            guess = scanner.nextLine();
            if (!guess.equalsIgnoreCase(a) && !guess.equalsIgnoreCase(b) && !guess.equalsIgnoreCase(c) && !guess.equalsIgnoreCase(d)&&!guess.equalsIgnoreCase(lifeline1)&& !guess.equalsIgnoreCase(lifeline2)&& !guess.equalsIgnoreCase(lifeline3)) {
              System.out.println("Invalid Input. Please Try Again. \n\n");
            }
          } while(!guess.equalsIgnoreCase(a) && !guess.equalsIgnoreCase(b) && !guess.equalsIgnoreCase(c) && !guess.equalsIgnoreCase(d)&&!guess.equalsIgnoreCase(lifeline1)&& !guess.equalsIgnoreCase(lifeline2)&& !guess.equalsIgnoreCase(lifeline3));

          System.out.println("Is this your final answer? (yes or no)");
          finalanswer=scanner.nextLine();

        } while(!finalanswer.equals(x));
        sum++; 
        if (guess.equals(answerkey[randomnum])) {
          System.out.println("You got it right!!! Congrats " + name+ " !! \n\n");
        }
        else {
          System.out.println("Sorry you got it wrong :(");
        }
      }
    }
    while(sum<=1) 
      if(guess.equalsIgnoreCase(lifeline3)) {
      System.out.println("You chose the call a friend lifeline!");
      do{
        System.out.println("Your friend says: Oh it's definitely A! I grew up watching the National Basketball Association and playing basketball!");
        do{
          System.out.println("What is your answer?");
          guess = scanner.nextLine();
          if ((!guess.equalsIgnoreCase(a) && !guess.equalsIgnoreCase(b) && !guess.equalsIgnoreCase(c) && !guess.equalsIgnoreCase(d)&& !guess.equalsIgnoreCase(lifeline1)&& !guess.equalsIgnoreCase(lifeline2)&&!guess.equalsIgnoreCase(lifeline3))) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input. Please Try Again. \n\n");
          }
        } while(!guess.equalsIgnoreCase(a) &&!guess.equalsIgnoreCase(b)&& !guess.equalsIgnoreCase(c) && !guess.equalsIgnoreCase(d)&& !guess.equalsIgnoreCase(lifeline1)&& !guess.equalsIgnoreCase(lifeline2)&& !guess.equalsIgnoreCase(lifeline3));

        System.out.println("Is this your final answer? (yes or no)");
        finalanswer=scanner.nextLine();

      } while(!finalanswer.equals(x));
      sum++;
        if (guess.equals(answerkey[randomnum])) {
        System.out.println("You got it right!!! Congrats " + name+ " !! \n\n");
      }
      else {
        System.out.println("Sorry you got it wrong :(");
      }
    }
  }




public static void main (String [] args  ) { 
  System.out.println("What's your name?");
  name = scanner.nextLine();
  System.out.println("Welcome to Who Wants to be a Millionaire! As I'm sure you know, you will have to answer 13 questions correctly in a row. \n But you have 3 lifelines to work with: 50/50, poll the audience, or ask a friend \n So, " + name+ " lets begin! You have a chance to win ONE MILLION DOLLARS!!! \n\n\n\n\n");
  questions();
  System.out.println("You are now at 100 Dollars!!!!");
  questions();
  questions();
  questions();
  questions();


}
}
```

Comment: Your first loop in `questions()` is an endless loop after the first method call. Use a debugger to understand why.

Comment: I deleted that loop but it still doesn't work

Comment: How did you find out that that the method only runs once? Is *"Remember, you can always use your lifelines."* really printed just one time?

Comment: yes it is only printed once

Comment: I would look at Sum. The static int sum gets appended in the first run - which means that the consequent runs will skip most of the while (sum<=1).